# Extract every nth number from a txt file

Tags: sed, awk, terminal

So I have a txt file where I need to extract every third number and print it to separate file using Terminal. The txt file is just a long list of numbers, tab delimited:

```
18 25 0 18 24 5 18 23 5 18 22 8.2 ...
```

I know there is a way to do this using sed or awk, but so far I've only been able to extract every third line by using:

```
awk 'NR%3==1' testRain.txt > rainOnly.txt
```

---

***So here's the answer*** (or rather, the answer I utilized!):

```
xargs -n1 < input.txt | awk '!(NR%3)' > output.txt
```

This gives you an `output.txt` that has every third number of the original file as a separate line.

Comment: Do you want to extract every third *character*, or every third *number*?

Comment: Post your expected output so we aren't left guessing.

Comment: sorry! every third number, so output would be 0 5 5 8.2

Comment: Question edited to say "number" instead of "character".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick pipe line to extract every 3rd number:

```
$ xargs -n1 < file | sed '3~3!d'
0
5
5
8.2
```

If you don't want each number on a newline throw the result back through `xargs`:

```
$ xargs -n1 < file | sed '3~3!d' | xargs
0 5 5 8.2
```

Use redirection to store the output in a new file:

```
$ xargs -n1 < file | sed '3~3!d' | xargs > new_file
```

---

With `awk` using a simple `for` loop you could do:

```
$ awk '{for(i=3;i<=NF;i+=3)print $i}' file
0
5
5
8.2
```

or *(adds a trailing tab)*:

```
$ awk '{for(i=3;i<=NF;i+=3)printf "%s\t",$i;print ""}' file
0   5   5   8.2
```

---

Or by setting the value of `RS` *(adds trailing newline)*:

```
$ awk '!(NR%3)' RS='\t' file
0
5
5
8.2

$ awk '!(NR%3)' RS='\t' ORS='\t' file
0   5   5   8.2
```

Comment: I like this one-line xargs fix, but I'm getting this error: 

sed: 1: "3~3!d": invalid command code ~

is this because I'm using OS X? I think there are some sed tricks that you have to employ for Macs but I can't seem to find the answer online right now...

Comment: I tried on OS X I had the same problem so use `awk '!(NR%3)'` instead of `sed '3~3!d'`. I'm no `sed` expert but @potong is so I'm sure he could advise *(although the `awk` command is just a good and short here + portable)*

Comment: FWIW I've been using sed for 30+ years and I couldn't tell you what `3~3!d` is supposed to do! I'd actually go with either of the awk scripts at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: awesome; thanks! I'll put `awk` answer in my original question so folks can see it easily

Comment: @EdMorton the first digit is the address of the line to start at (third line) the `~` operator specifies the of-set (every third line) and `!d` is negated deleted. So `1~2!d` prints all odd lines and `2~2!d` prints all even.

Answer (score 1):

You can print every third character by substituting the next two with nothing, globally. When the count straddles a newline, using Perl might be the simplest solution:

```
perl -p000 -e 's/(.)../$1/gs'
```

If you want the first, fourth etc character from every line, a line-oriented tool like `sed` suffices:

```
sed 's/\(.\)../\1/g'
```

Comment: Thanks for the upvote.  I guess this is now moot, as the OP clarified that he meant "number" when he wrote "character" ...

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep -P`

```
grep -oP '([^\t]+\t){2}\K[^\t\n]+' file
0
5
5
8.2
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(\S+\s){3}/\1/g;s/\s$//' file
```

Answer (score 0):

@user2718946
Your solution was close, but here you are without xarg.

```
awk 'NR%3==1' RS=" " file
18
18
18
18
```

Different start:

```
awk 'NR%3==0' RS=" " file
0
5
5
8.2
```